# How can I efficiently generate a 'dense' path though a grid that can be traced by a single non-intersecting line?

Tags: javascript, path-finding

I wanted to try to make a game that is essentially what I describe in the title. The user is given a grid, and they must connect all the grid points using a single line, without ever visiting the same node twice. I didn't want to have levels hard-coded; I would like them to be dynamically generated each time.

The solution I came up with (which can be demoed [here](https://calvin-godfrey.github.io/Snake/index.html)), is essentially to generate a random walk of a certain length within a bounded area. If it starts a random walk and realizes that it gets stuck and can't find any moves, just give up and try again.

```
/* This function returns true if it
      successfully generates a valid
      path. The function that calls
      this repeatedly does so until
      it returns true. */
function generateWalk() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * WIDTH); // WIDTH, HEIGHT are arbitrary constants
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * HEIGHT); // generates random starting location
  for (var k=0;k<LENGTH;k++) {
    grid[j][i].active = true; // out of the WIDTH * HEIGHT possible grid cells, only a certain number
                              // are actually used. This identifies which they are.
    grid[j][i].index = k + 1; // Record's which location in the sequence the given node is.
    var newi, newj;
    var index = 0;
    while (true) { // Try to take another step
      index++;
      var option = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
      newi = i + (option == 0) - (option == 1); // Fancy math that maps 0 -> right, 1 -> left,
      newj = j + (option == 2) - (option == 3); //                      2 -> down,  3 -> up
      if (newi >= 0 && newi < WIDTH && newj >= 0 && newj < HEIGHT && !grid[newj][newi].active) {
        break; // if the step is valid
      }
      if (index == 100) { // If we've tried to take a random step 100 times, we're stuck
        return false;
      }
    }
    i = newi;
    j = newj;
  }
  return true;
}
```

As it should be apparent, my solution is just trial-and-error; try to generate a path with the given restrictions and hope that *eventually*, it will generate a valid one. And this works fine when `LENGTH/(WIDTH * HEIGHT)` is small (i.e. most grid cells aren't used). But when `LENGTH` approaches `(WIDTH * HEIGHT)/2`, that's when my browser starts to freeze and I'm forced to refresh it. And ideally, I'd like to be able to generate more dense puzzles, instead of the rather sparse ones that this can generate easily.

So is there an alternative that can generate random (or at least *kinda* random) paths when I went them to be denser?

One alternative that I just thought of while writing this question is to choose the set of `LENGTH` grid points that I want to use in the final path, then *after* that step is done, figure out how to link them together to make a single path. Would that be a better alternative?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a Hamiltonian cycle on the grid?

Comment: I think the proper term would be Hamiltonian path, not cycle -- it doesn't have to start and end in the same position. But looking into it, yes I suppose I am.

Comment: Right, my mistake! The problem with that is that if you block off part of the grid in the wrong way, you may not be able to generate a Hamiltonian path on it. Another idea is using backtracking instead of trying 100 directions. If you get stuck, backtrack to the last location where you can make progress and continue random walking but don't carve the failed path. Like the recursive backtracking maze algorithm but without walls between adjacent locations. Do these seem promising? Also, you don't need to try 100 directions; take an array of 4 directions and shuffle. That's a "free" improvement.